# How to manage the number of rows in a section?

Tags: iphone

I am using a table view in one of myapplications. In that number of sections are one and number of rows are 20. And i want to place the image and two lables in that every row. So to fill up the rows,i written the below code in `CellForrowIndexpath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      }
      int i=indexPath.row;
      if (indexPath.row==i)
      {

          cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

          UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
          UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
          //UILabel *lblTemp3 = (UILabel *)[tableCell viewWithTag:3];
           lblTemp1.text = [ctrycodearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           lblTemp2.text = @"Alert";

          UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 30)];
          img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_mdpi.png"];

          //NSString *cellValue1 = [default1 stringForKey:@"keyToRepeatString"];
          //repeatlbl.text=cellValue1;   

          //[img release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:img];

          return cell;
      }
```

In the `getCellContentView` method i declared the two lables.After executing this one i got the error.This `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method executed 6 or 7 times and print the 6 or 7 rows>but if move to top the below errowill occured.So please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: what u are doing in getCellContentView?

Comment: mention the labels frames and properties for that lables and return the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use custom UITableViewCell for these kind of things.

Ref: [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Try as per this doc & if u hav any problem, pl. post that here.

Edit: Don't need to read the whole doc. Just have a look at `Listing 5-3  Adding subviews to a cell’s content view` in that link.

Comment: but for this simple use it`s too much code in custom cell. insted of that he can add(setup) custom lable at run time ... in UITableViewCell.

Comment: I have narrowed down the code to be go through. See my edited post above.

Comment: You at least need to skim the documentation to know what is in there.